# Strange BLDC motor sensor sequence

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Chinese BLDC motor from "Cloudrive-tech",

When phases (P1, P2, P3) excited, the hall sensors (H1, H2, H3) give the following reading sequence for CW direction:

1. FLH => 100(4)
2. HLF => 101(5)
3. HFL => 011(3) // Should be 001(1)
4. FHL => 011(3)
5. LHF => 010(2)
6. LFH => 110(6)

Where (F=Float, L=Low, H=High)

In step 3, fine turning the axe by hand under low PWM, alternates between the settled reading (3) and the expected reading (1), elsewhere it settles to the wrong value (3).

For that I altered the control firmware from simple look-up table assignment, to this:

```
void BM60L300V3_Commutate(void)
{
    uint8_t i;

    // Read H1:H2:H3..
    i = (uint8_t)(Status.DIReg & 0x07); // 1st 3 bits..

    // Previous value error tweak..
    if(i == 3)
    {
        if(STATE_IS_SET(SB_CCW)) // CCW..
        {
            if(BM60L300V3_SensorPrevVal == 3) // Check previous value.
            {
                i = 1;
            }
        }
        else // CW..
        {
            if(BM60L300V3_SensorPrevVal == 5) // Check previous value.
            {
                i = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    BM60L300V3_SensorPrevVal = i; // Update previous value.

    // Output..
    POUT_PORT = POutCrnt[i];
}
```

And it successfully commutates

It's not my 1st time with sensor-based BLDC control, & I didn't face such issue before,

Do I miss something!

Notes:

1. I emailed the company with no answer!
2. After PWM > 40% approximately, there are rotational lags & sensor reading stretching on oscilloscope.

Update: In the firmware, there's a diagnostic mode which I use to identify the correct wiring, measurements and so. In this mode I set the phase output and read back the corresponding hall sensor readings. F => the phase is OFF, H => The phase is V+, L => The phase is GND.

The motor specifications:
[image: BM60L300V3 specifications]

Comment: hall sensor skew is a sign of MFG process quality control issue which can be corrected but causes dead spots and phase skips

Comment: What do you mean by 'float', ' high', and 'low'? What type of Hall sensors does this motor have? How are you measuring the output?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I added an update to clarify (F, H, L) .. The only known information about the sensors is the wiring and the operating voltage of 5VDC .. Beside the firmware sensor reading, I measure the sensor output directly on the wire connector too.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you mean by 'float'. If you rotate the motor slowly by hand (without powering any phases) what waveform does each sensor output trace? Can you show us the wiring to the sensors? Your motor appears to be part of an e-bike package and I can't find any reference to it as a separate item. Where did you get it?